# How can I work around a Scala compiler crash?

Tags: scala

I am compiling a project with Scala 2.9.1 and getting

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.accessed(Symbols.scala:1142)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.accessed(Symbols.scala:1138)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin$MixinTransformer$$anonfun$buildFieldPositions$1$1.apply(Mixin.scala:1006)
```

I guess it's a bug, but I don't really have time to fix it or wait for someone else to fix it, so I'd like to just change whatever I'm doing so I don't hit the bug.

But I'm having a hard time because I get no clue about what part of my code caused the problem. Are there any strategies I can use to isolate the problem?

To make things easier for those investigating, here are the links to the source code:

- [Symbols.scala:1142](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/symtab/Symbols.scala#L1142)
- [Symbols.scala:1138](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/symtab/Symbols.scala#L1138)
- [Mixin.scala:1006](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/Mixin.scala#L1006)

Comment: Please file a bug if you have found the cause.

Comment: Do you have a `@transient` annotation by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked around Scala compiler crashes, in specific, but I have worked around other compiler crashes.  What you want to do is to try narrowing down what's causing the problem.  The easiest way to do this in most projects is to do a binary search via commenting.  That is, comment out about half of the code and see if the bug still happens.  If not, uncomment that half and comment the other half and see if the bug still happens.  Then, assuming that this works and you find which half it's occurring in, break that in half via comments.  Repeat this process until you're down to the smallest segment of code which you can find which still breaks things.  (Obviously, you may not always be able to do even halves due to code dependencies, but find ways to break it, at least, into big chunks).

When you get there, you may find, by inspection, that there is a bug in that code because compiler crashes, in my experience, are more likely to be caused by incorrectly formed code which is incorrectly formed in a manner that the compiler author didn't expect.  For example, my own intellisense-like Java module that I wrote for work would crash on `foo(super).bar` because I'd never imagined anyone not following super with a period or open paren but it could slip through the parser due to how the grammar was designed.  And Adobe's Actionscript compiler would crash when you wrote `var x:int : 10;` rather than `var x:int = 10;` (they may have fixed that now, but it would crash there last time I used it).  So, if you do find a bug in your code, fix it.  If not, just try to rewrite that code so that it's different.  Hopefully you'll be able to find a version which doesn't cause a compiler crash.

Comment: Thank you. Binary search with a comment worked. I would have replied earlier but that project was overwhelming my time.

Answer (score 2):

If you could make your code do a println *while compiling*, I'm sure you could narrow it down in no time.  So why not do something equivalent?

```
0.0.0                                 // Lexer will choke on this (I think)
val var;                              // Parser will choke on this
val Some(x) = None;                   // Second pass will, I think, choke on this
Option(2) match { case Some(x) => x } // Will emit warning in late phase and continue
```

You can drop these in your code in various places as tests to see how far the compiler gets before choking; this should let you narrow down to a few lines where it may be more practical to comment/uncomment blocks of code.

Also, make sure you build from scratch when you run into something like this; the compiler sometimes dies when there are incompatible versions and it doesn't recognize that it needs to recompile something to get the changes.

Comment: If you want to limit the phase, there are compiler flags for that.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: I found it while following the error messages ... damnit ... didn't saw the first error message. I'm stupid. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been using source control and working incrementally (you **have** been using source control and working incrementally, yes?) then you already know what's caused the problem - it's the last thing you changed. Because you've been working incrementally, this will be a small change, and because you've been using source control you know exactly what it is, because you've got a complete history of everything you've done.

Cut this change down into the smallest change that still reproduces the problem (most likely by using a binary chop). Something about this change will be "strange", and that's what's confusing the compiler. Find a way to solve the problem without using whatever this "strange" thing is and you've got your workaround.

But before you do that, please report the bug (any occasion where the compiler crashes is definitely a bug), together with a small example that illustrates it.

If you've not been working incrementally and using source control, you have a **much** more tedious task:

1. First, work out which file is causing the problem (use a binary chop to narrow this down until you've identified a single file).
2. Next, identify which bit of this file is causing the problem (binary chop again).
3. Keep binary chopping until you've got your single, simple change.

Answer (score 1):

Scala trunk prints more information, so if you could compile it with trunk just to get a better error message, it would help. Of course, it is possible that trunk doesn't have this bug, but it is worth a shot.

If compiling with trunk doesn't help, here's what I know. This is related to getters and setters. From the code, it could be either the setter or the getter. It does seem to be something that is called when the getter or setter is *used*, not defined. You could look up those.

Also, please pay attention to getter and setter rules. A getter *must* have at least as much visibility as the setter (ie, public if the setter is public, etc). And, since we are talking about a compiler bug here, I'd avoid weird visibilities (ie, anything not public or private), inheritance or mixed visibilities (eg, setter private and getter public).

**EDIT:** I just noticed the stack trace mentions mixin as well. So, it is related to a getter or setter which is defined in a trait and used on a class, or used on a trait.

**EDIT 2:** Still investigating. Do you have overload getters/setters for lazy vals, or getters/setters being overloaded with lazy vals? Or, just lazy vals on traits? I saw something in the third line of the trace that seems to point to a lazy val.

If you do find more information, please try to reproduce a small case of it, to submit an issue.